# Autoscale while excluding specific artists in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm plotting a group of `matplotlib` `Artist`s on top of a much larger background `Artist` (an image displayed through `imshow`). I would like to autoscale the axes to "zoom in" on those particular artists with some given margin, in the style of `plt.margins()` and `ax.autoscale_view()`. Neither method works out of the box since the bounds of the large background image are taken as the overall bounds.

I've seen some questions about excluding *lines* from autoscaling (such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5437291/exclude-lines-from-autoscale-in-matplotlib)), but none about excluding an `Artist` in general. Since I'm dealing with `Artist`s like `Arc` and so on, there isn't a set of points I can easily manually calculate the bounding box of in order to `set_xlim` and `set_ylim` directly.

Does `matplotlib` have any built-in ability to, at the very least, compute the bounding box of a single arbitrary `Artist` or group thereof? Or, better yet, to autoscale while excluding certain `Artist`s?

Comment: If the artist derives from `Patch` (`Arc` does, IIRC), the class method `get_extents` gives you the bounding box. If the artists derives from `Line2D`, then you need to get the path first (`get_path`), which again has a `get_extents` method. You can get all artists on an axis with `ax.get_children`.